# Do the people who have liked a website need to like again the newly

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I have a website which has significant amount of likes. I want to create a facebook page for the website. Will those people who have already liked the website need to like the facebook page again? How can I retain those likes in the newly created facebook page?

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for questions related to programing.

Comment: Pierre, If there was a possibility then the answer of the "how" question would probably have required some solution with adjustments in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a user likes my Facebook Page or URL using Facebook's API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5093398/how-to-check-if-a-user-likes-my-facebook-page-or-url-using-facebooks-api)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no way to force or to transfer the likes of an URL to the facebook *fanpage*.
So, yes you need to ask, with a like button, the users to like the fanpage.